# How to Change TextView color and ImageView Image on ListView Click event in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to change Textview Color and Imageview image on listview click event & i also create custom listview .I want that when i click on a listview item to change image and text color and go to another Activity, but when i go back to list activity and click other list item to change textcolor and image as well as change first click item color and image..my code given below:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                channel_listView, R.layout.listview_layout1, from, to);
        listView.setDivider(null);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    long c_name = listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
                    Log.i("c_name", "" + c_name);

                    ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt))
                            .setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    ((ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.flag))
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowmusicicon);

                    String ch_name = (String) ((TextView) arg1
                            .findViewById(R.id.txt)).getText();
                    Log.i("txt_value", "" + ch_name);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ChannelList.this,
                            FMActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", c_name);
                    intent.putExtra("c_name", ch_name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: when you're back from the ChannelList Activity, your main activity is created again (onCreate is called) and so is you list. Therefore, it will show the initial colors and images you set as default in your xml. you need to store the new values (with SharedPreferences for example), and set them in your getView() method

Comment: but how to use SharedPreferences. Give Any Example please.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare:

```
SharedPrefernces mPrefs;
```

in on create:

```
mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("some name", 0);
```

to use value:

```
int value = mPrefs.getInt("value name",0);
```

to save value:

```
mPrefs.edit().putInt("value name",value);
mPrefs.edit().commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your manifest (to this activity):

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

or:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Your activity won't recreacte any more. It will be saved.
More info: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)